# Leetcode testing Linked list

Tags: c#, unit-testing, linked-list

I am trying to solve this question 
https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-medium/107/linked-list/785

[image]

I wrote my code and I am trying to test it

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace LinkedListQuestions
{
public class ListNode
    {
        public int val;
        public ListNode next;

        public ListNode(int x)
        {
            val = x;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-medium/107/linked-list/785
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class GetIntersectionNodeTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  intersectVal = 8, listA = [4,1,8,4,5], listB = [5,0,1,8,4,5], skipA = 2, skipB = 3
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            ListNode listA = new ListNode(4);
            listA.next = new ListNode(1);
            listA.next.next = new ListNode(8);
            listA.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
            listA.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);

            ListNode listB = new ListNode(5);
            listB.next = new ListNode(0);
            listB.next.next = new ListNode(1);
            listB.next.next.next = new ListNode(8);
            listB.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
            listB.next.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);
            GetIntersectionNodeClass intersection= new GetIntersectionNodeClass();
            ListNode res = intersection.GetIntersectionNode(listA, listB);
           Assert.AreEqual(8,res.val);
        }
    }

    public class GetIntersectionNodeClass
    {
        public ListNode GetIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB)
        {
            if (headA == null || headB == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            ListNode currA = headA;
            ListNode currB = headB;
            while (currA != currB)
            {
                if (currA == null)
                {
                    currA = headB;
                }
                else
                {
                    currA = currA.next;
                }

                if (currB == null)
                {
                    currB = headA;
                }
                else
                {
                    currB = currB.next;
                }
            }

            return currA;
        }
    }
}
```

my code works for leetcode however I tried to write one unit test for it, according to their example. but my code return null and not the expected result.
I guess I am missing some comparison IComparable, but why does it work for Leetcode?? 
Thanks

Comment: Time to step through your code, statement by statement, in a debugger?

Comment: Time to learn to read the question?

Comment: Going by the image, I wouldn't call that list intersection. Instead there are two heads of two lists that merges into a single tail. Your lists in the `TestMethod1` doesn't merge that way, they only contain the same values at their different and distinct tail ends. For it to be like the image, you should do `listB.next.next.next = listA.next.next;` and not add more elements to `listB` after that.

Comment: This might help ? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-get-the-intersection-point-of-two-linked-lists/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fix for the test like "Some Programmer dude" suggested

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    ListNode listA = new ListNode(4);
    listA.next = new ListNode(1);
    listA.next.next = new ListNode(8);
    listA.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
    listA.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);

    ListNode listB = new ListNode(5);
    listB.next = new ListNode(0);
    listB.next.next = new ListNode(1);
    listB.next.next.next = listA.next.next;
    listB.next.next.next.next = listA.next.next.next;
    listB.next.next.next.next.next = listA.next.next.next.next;
    GetIntersectionNodeClass intersection= new GetIntersectionNodeClass();
    ListNode res = intersection.GetIntersectionNode(listA, listB);
   Assert.AreEqual(8,res.val);
}
```